# PHP header url redirect

Tags: php, html

I've searched around the inter webs and have been unable to find a solution for my problem.  Here is my problem, I have a post script that enters the user's post and user id in the database.  What I want to do is from different pages on my web site, after it posts, to redirect back to the page that the user was just on.  And all of it will take place after the user has logged into the website, so it's not a way to redirect to the login page, but back to the page the user was on after submitting a post.  The problem is it goes to profile_test2.php even though I posted from homepage.php.

Here is my code from my form:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="POST" action="add_post.php?bev=1">
<input type="text" name="textbox" id="textbox" spellcheck="true">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And here is the code in the php script:

```
// Get the page the user posted from
$page = $_GET['bev'];

//Redirect this user to the page that displays user information
if ($_GET['bev'] == '1') {
$url = 'homepage.php';
} else if ($_GET['bev'] == '2') {
$url = 'profile_test2.php';
} else {
$url = 'profile_test2.php';
}

header('Location: '. $url);
exit();
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the problem, what doesn't work? What value is `$url`? What errors are you getting, if any?

Comment: It goes to profile_test2.php, it doesn't go back to the homepage if that's where I am, it'll redirect to profile_test2

Comment: I'm not totally sure right now how a POST form should handle the GET argument (I would think it should work, but...), anyway the easy route would be to have `bev` as an invisible element in your form: `<input type="hidden" name="bev" value="1">`

Comment: Wow, that was too easy.  That did the trick, thank you so much. @Pekka웃

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for Pekka's comment on using invisible element in the form instead of having GET variable passing through POST form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="bev" value="1">
```

If the page always redirect to profile_test2.php most probably the GET function is not working and it always falls under `ELSE` condition in the php script. You may wanna `echo the $url` just to double check on this.

Answer (score 0):

Can't have a form `action` with a `$_GET` url. You can use an `<input type='hidden' name='bev' value='1' />` though. Since your method is `$_POST` I would use `$_POST['bev']`.